# Format the values "doesn't work'

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Using the function to format the value and calling like this :

```
$(".vlrTotal").val(formatReal(formatarValor($(".vlrTotal").val())));
```

My Html:

```
<td>
    <input readonly type="text" name="vlrTotal[]" value="<?php echo $item['VwEstPedOnlineItens']['vlr_custo_total']; ?>" class="vlrTotal" style="width: 100%;"/>
</td>
```

And results this image above.

Now if I take off the function to format the value, the result is this:
[image]

The problem is, with the value formatted, all inputs `(".vlrTotal")` shows the same value ( The first one ), but when I inspect the element, the value shows the right Value. If I take off the function to format the value, It "works".

I don't know what to do anymore.

PS: The Console.log :

> input.vlrTotal property value = "7.199,28" attribute value = "2799.72"
>
> input.vlrTotal property value = "7.199,28" attribute value = "2399.76"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple elements with `$(".vlrTotal")`, you need to iterate and set value to each element. When you access the `.val()` method it fetches value of first element as you experienced.

You need use [`.val( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)

> A function returning the value to set. this is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

*Use*

```
$(".vlrTotal").val(function(_, value){
    return formatReal(formatarValor(value));
});
```

*OR*, simple `$.fn.each()`

```
$(".vlrTotal").each(function(){
    $(this).val(formatReal(formatarValor($(this).val())));
});
```

Note: Assuming you have defined `formatReal` and `formatarValor` function with desired behavior.

Comment: BUT, he's formatting just the first result, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

By using `$(".vlrTotal").val(formatReal(formatarValor($(".vlrTotal").val())));` you are setting the same value for every single element that matches your selector `.vlrTotal`.

You have to iterate through the list of elements in order to change each element individually.

```
$(".vlrTotal").each(function(){
    $(this).val(formatReal(formatarValor($(this).val())));
});
```

Comment: It worked !  BUT, he's formatting just the first result, not all of them.

Comment: Sorry!  Fixed the code, had error where although it was formatting every field, it was using the value of the first field.  By using `$(this)`, as you iterate through each element you are reference the current element